# Code to view the excel sheet data in Grid with checkbox, Oncheck save in database in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Can you please provide me sample code to view the excel sheet data in Grid with checkbox,Oncheck  save in database in mvc (.NET 4.0 framework)
Step By Step Implementation:
1.  Add Upload File button
2.  Add excel file from browser.
3.   Upload file into some folder.
4.  Bind Grid by data contain in excel sheet with one checkbox
5.  By Check the checkbox, the row which is checked is stored in database by save click.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-Sheet-into-ASP.Net-GridView-Control.aspx), which will cover some points as below:

- Uploading excel sheet
- Importing excel sheet into gridview
- Display it to the user

Other parts such as checkbox and saving it to the database task, I think you can go ahead and do some search on your own as this article gives some starting point for you.